# ms access combining rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

This seems like it should be a simple solution but for some reason i cannot wrap my head around this.

I have a table that has `USER_FULL_NAME` as the primary key and about 15 columns of various metrics to the right. I have some instances where multiple `USER_FULL_NAME`'s are spelled incorrectly but should in fact be summed up into the same row. Ie. "David Hands" could be spelt as "Davide Handes" and "Bobby Orr" could be spelt as "Boby Or." There are roughly 150 rows total in the table but there are about 136 unique `USER_FULL_NAME`.

How can i write an SQL query to merge the 150 rows into the unique 136 rows where the `USER_FULL_NAME` that should be combined are in fact combined??

---

I have added another column to a matrix table called `TPS_User_names`, one for `USER_FULL_NAME` and one for `DUPLICATE_USER_FULL_NAME`. This is the query that i've come up with but does not seem to work:

```
select

tun.user_full_name,

sum(ad.processed_mss)

from all_data ad left join tps_user_names tun on ad.user_full_name = tun.user_full_name and ad.user_full_name = tun.duplicate_user_full_name

where ad.user_full_name = 'A' and ad.user_full_name = 'A1'

group by tun.user_full_name
```

Comment: There is not a way to really automate this without some serious coding checking for different patterns. You are able to see it as a person because you are applying multiple patterns very quickly without really thinking about it. How would you put that into code? Just to make it more extreme think of it trying to figure out that sCUS gBSA = David Hands. I would correct the data manually.

Comment: Not a coding solution, but you could create a matrix table which has two columns, the duplicated USER_FULL_NAMEs and the actual USER_FULL_NAME, OUTER JOIN to this table and use the acutal USER_FULL_NAME whenever you do your aggregations.  Short of revisiting your schema or correcting the errors in the table itself, this is the best way, imo.  In the case it keeps happening, you add a row to your matrix table instead of changing your code.

Comment: @VBlades do you mean left join? I cannot perform an outer join in MS access

Comment: @JT2013: Yup, LEFT JOIN is fine.  Other than that, does what I say make sense to you?  Need any clarification?

Comment: @VBlades have a look at the query that ive created above...i cannot seem to get your solution to work...

Comment: @JT2013: select Nz(tun.user_full_name, ad.user_full_name) As user_full_name_agg, sum(ad.processed_mss)
from all_data ad left join tps_user_names tun on ad.user_full_name = tun.duplicate_user_full_name 
group by Nz(tun.user_full_name, ad.user_full_name);

Comment: @JT2013: The Nz will select the first non-null value from tun.user_full_name or ad.user_full_name it finds.  So for the dupes, it will use the consolidated user_full_name it finds in tun, for others, the one in ad.  Also. pull your WHERE clause out first.  See if it works before then see if you can work it back in.  The way it was, it wouldn't have brought up any rows anyway.

Comment: @JT2013: If the query doesn't work still, post your data as well.  This solution will definitely work if done properly.

Comment: @VBlades please post your query as an answer so that I can give you credit...thanks a bunch!

Comment: @JT2013: You're welcome, glad your issue is sorted out.  Posted an answer, hopefully it can be of use to someone else in the future as well.  Take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not strictly a coding solution, but you could create a matrix table which has two columns, the duplicated USER_FULL_NAMEs and the actual USER_FULL_NAME, LEFT JOIN to this table and use the actual USER_FULL_NAME whenever you do your aggregations. Short of revisiting your schema or correcting the errors in the table itself, this is the best way, imo. In the case it keeps happening, you add a row to your matrix table instead of changing your code.  (It should also be noted you can use an interim step involving the matrix table to re-normalize your original table.  Key relationship issues aside, you can create the matrix, pull the aggregated query, then use this to reinsert into/update your original table.)

**EDIT:**  As you have supplied your code, here are the modifications you can make to integrate your new table into the mix:

```
SELECT    Nz(tun.user_full_name, ad.user_full_name) As user_full_name_agg,
          SUM(ad.processed_mss)
FROM      all_data ad LEFT JOIN tps_user_names tun
          ON ad.user_full_name = tun.duplicate_user_full_name
GROUP BY  Nz(tun.user_full_name, ad.user_full_name);
```

The Nz will select the first non-null value from tun.user_full_name or ad.user_full_name it finds. So for the dupes, it will use the consolidated user_full_name it finds in tun, for others, the one in ad.

Answer (score 2):

This is hardly a trivial problem to get right in practice, even if it may be easy to the eye to catch "similar" and thus assumed identical names.

Think about it--if you were to do this algorithmically, you would have tons of borderline cases where you -- or the computer -- would  need to make the call: Is Jon Smith the same as John Smith, or Jon P Smith? Maybe. Maybe not.

Unless you have other identifiers there is no way to know, which means you will have hard time getting meaningful aggregations from it. One way to do fuzzy text matching is to calculate Levenshtein distances, a way to quantify how close two strings are to one another, but for the reasons mentioned, you may still get false positives.

If your problem is a recurring one (as in, in need of frequent updates) you may want to re-think your database structure and have a primary key that is not the actual name, and look at how new entries are added to the table. That is the ideal, if possible, time to assess if you are dealing with a new user name.

For a one off, I would query out the 16 rows that do have duplicates and assess individually.

Comment: +1, I had a friend Mary K who was married to Mark, and this caused them trouble in reservation systems.  A very difficult problem.

Comment: i know the 6 `user_full_name`'s and would like to manually maintain them...what is the best possible way to write this query?